# Applications that are not installed appear in Unity?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, unity

When browsing the Unity menu, I get strange entries. Such as if I search "Monitor" for system monitor, I get entries for Camera Monitor and Battery Monitor, things I know are not installed. Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh , those are some apps that are available to install from the Ubuntu Software Centre =) Everytime you search for apps , it will display the apps you have installed and apps that are available from the software centre . Its a faster way to search for apps from Ubuntu Software Centre =)

Comment: Thanks! That is good to know, I was just confused was all. :)